# why Mainwindow is closed during pressing the OK button of the messagebox

Tags: qt4

i have a mainwindow and a button.i am parsing one xml and the rwesult is displayed in messagebox...when i pressed ok button of messagebox it show the next loop of xml...and at the end mainwindow is also closed.i dont want to close the mainwindow....how to achieve it?????

Comment: I had a similar [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584824/adding-a-qspacer-to-qgridlayout-more-than-once-is-causing-mychilddialog-accept) that I managed to solve. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the mainwindow is a dialog. Try to change the type of the form (FormBorderStyle property).
Maybe, you should change property AcceptButton.